# Binding UserControl DependencyProperty to other UserControl DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, silverlight, dependency-properties

I have two UserControls:

```
public partial class MKSelectMonthUC : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentYearProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentYear", typeof(int), typeof(MKSelectMonthUC), new PropertyMetadata(0));
    public int CurrentYear
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(CurrentYearProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(CurrentYearProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ChatRoomIdProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ChatRoomId", typeof(int), typeof(MKSelectMonthUC), new PropertyMetadata(0));
    public int ChatRoomId
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(ChatRoomIdProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ChatRoomIdProperty, value);
            if(value > 0)
                GetChatReport(ChatRoomId);
        }
    }
```

}

and

```
public partial class MKSelectPeriodForChatReportCW : ChildWindow
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ChatRoomIdProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ChatRoomId", typeof(int), typeof(MKSelectPeriodForChatReportCW), new PropertyMetadata(0));
    public int ChatRoomId
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(ChatRoomIdProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ChatRoomIdProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentYearProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentYear", typeof(int), typeof(MKSelectPeriodForChatReportCW), new PropertyMetadata(0));
    public int CurrentYear
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(CurrentYearProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(CurrentYearProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

}

in XAML of MKSelectPeriodForChatReportCW I want to bind it's DependencyProperties to MKSelectMonthUC DependencyProperties like that:

```xml
<controls:ChildWindow x:Class="XX.mkControls.MKSelectPeriodForChatReportCW"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
       xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"
       xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit" 
       xmlns:mk="clr-namespace:XX.mkControls.MKSelectPeriodForChatReport"
       Name="mainControl"
       >
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="2">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <mk:MKSelectMonthUC CurrentYear="{Binding CurrentYear, ElementName=mainControl}" ChatRoomId="{Binding ChatRoomId, ElementName=mainControl}" />


</Grid>
```

Properties on MKSelectPeriodForChatReportCW do get values (from their bindings) but values on MKSelectMonthUC don't. So please help me find a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Are you expecting `GetChatReport(ChatRoomId)` to be triggered by a change in the related control? Setters and Getters are not used by the bindings, which only use `SetValue` and `GetValue`. They are only there for your convenience. Supply a change handler to that dependency property instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have all your source code and I cannot reproduce your problem, so all I can do is to make some suggestions based on the style of code you've presented above.

1. As HiTechMagic says, the `GetChatReport` method call in the `ChatRoomId` setter in `MKSelectMonthUC` won't get called as often as you might expect.  If you want a method to be called every time a dependency property changes, use a `PropertyChangedCallback`.  [This page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903933%28v=vs.95%29.aspx#metadata) has an example of how to use a PropertyChangedCallback.

   For a property backed by a dependency property, the getter should only contain a call to `GetValue` and the setter should only contain a call to `SetValue`.
2. Bindings using `ElementName` can be awkward to work with because they are silent if something goes wrong (e.g. no element with the given name was found).  Presumably you have values for your `CurrentYear` and `ChatRoomId` properties somewhere in your view-model, and if so,  I'd recommend binding both `CurrentYear` and both `ChatRoomId` dependency properties to data in your view-model.
3. Bindings between two dependency properties are best used with presentation-layer information.  For example, you might use a binding between two dependency properties to ensure two controls are the same width.  The width of these controls is presentation-layer data since it isn't *what* data you're presenting, but it's *how* you're presenting it.  Your `CurrentYear` and `ChatRoomId` properties are the data you're showing, not how you're showing it, so they're not presentation-layer data.

I would also recommend against giving top-level elements a `Name` or an `x:Name` and then using that name in a binding.  Admittedly, the only XAML you've shown is your `ChildWindow`, so I don't know whether your `MKSelectMonthUC` user-control does the same.  Nonetheless, for future reference, and for anyone else reading this answer, I'll give two reasons why this is a bad idea.

Suppose we have the following `UserControl`:

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="XYZ.MyUserControl"
             ....
             x:Name="myUc">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MyProperty, ElementName=myUc}" />
</UserControl>
```

If we then attempt to use this control and give it a different `x:Name`, such as

```xml
<xyz:MyUserControl x:Name="abc123" />
```

we end up changing the name of the control from `myUc` to `abc123`, and this breaks the binding.

Furthermore, if we attempt to use two or more of these user controls, for example

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <xyz:MyUserControl />
    <xyz:MyUserControl />
</StackPanel>
```

then we get an error about `x:Name`s not being unique, as both `MyUserControl` elements have an `x:Name` of `myUc`.